# How to disconnect from a wireless network in Gnome 3.10

Tags: wireless, gnome, network-manager

I wanted to start my hotspot (using [ap-hotspot](https://github.com/hotice/AP-Hotspot)). To enable it, you have to disconnect from the wireless network you're connected to.

This was no problem in Gnome 3.8's network manager, but I cannot find a similar functionallity in Gnome 3.10.

The only way I found to disconnect is clicking on "forget this network". Is there a way to just disconnect without forgetting all my settings?

**Edit**:

```
$ gnome-control-center --version
gnome-control-center 3.10.1
```

Just in case somebody has an old control center but a new gnome shell. ;-)

Comment: Could I ask from which ppa/source did you install Gnome 3.10?

Comment: @Sneetsher [`ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3)

Comment: Could try its command line client `nmcli d disconnect iface wlan0` (change network interface name)

Comment: @Sneetsher thanks, that works. I think I'll include this in my `ap-hotspot` script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the below GUI method was not valid for gnome-control-center 3.10. It is possible to use `nmcli` (command‐line tool for controlling NetworkManager)

```
nmcli d disconnect iface wlan0
```

- `d` for device
- `disconnect` command to disconnect network interface
- `iface wlan0` network interface name (Check from `ifconfig -a` or `iwconfig`)

otherway, using connection id:

```
nmcli c down id WiFiConn
```

- `c` for connection
- `down` command to drop connection
- `id WiFiConn` name of connection as it was saved in NetworkManager (Check `nmcli c`).

Reference: [`man nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html)

---

This for gnome-control-center 3.6.3 (still used by Ubuntu 14.04). From Gnome indicator bar:

1. Wi-Fi → WiFi Settings

   [image]
2. Click on arrow to the right of current active connection

   [image]
3. Disconnect

   [image]

Comment: I would totally agree if this button would be there. This is the way I did it before the upgrade to Gnome 3.10. This is how it looks on my machine: [Image 1](http://i.imgur.com/2U5YQ22.png), [Image 2](http://i.imgur.com/uClK7KN.png).

Comment: Weird, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, gnome-control-center `1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56`, what's your gnome-control-center version?

Comment: `gnome-control-center --version` prints `gnome-control-center 3.10.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you click on your wifi settings in the upper right notification panel ?
When you expand the details, you should find a "Shut off" option, or something similar (I'm using French translated Gnome).

Comment: This disables WiFi completely, but I just want to disconnect from the current access point.

Comment: If you need to create a hotspot on your computer, you need to go to WiFi Settings (in the upper right notification panel) and click the "Create a Hotspot" button in the bottom of the window.

Comment: This doesn't support custom SSIDs, passphrases and is just WEP encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Click on turn of I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome 3.10 from official repositories.And ap-hotspot works fine for me.Hope this helped.

[image]

Comment: `Turn off` will turn WiFi off and doesn't disconnect from the current network.